# Illegal preprocessor directive and Symbol referenced at (1) not found in module

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to compile a Quantum ESPRESSO code with some other packages. After playing around with the Makefile and compiling flags a bit, I "obtained" an error as below. Is there any way to get around this? Am I missing any flag to avoid the error? Or does it come from the code itself?

```
$ mpif90 -fdollar-ok -ffree-line-length-none -O3 -fopenmp -fPIC -I ../../../qe/6.0-mpi/Modules -I ../src -I ../src ../../../qe/6.0-mpi/PW/src/libpw.a ../../../qe/6.0-mpi/Modules/libqemod.a ../../../qe/6.0-mpi/FFTXlib/libqefft.a ../../../qe/6.0-mpi/LAXlib/libqela.a -Wall -c qevars.f90 
Warning: qevars.f90:30: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: qevars.f90:32: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: qevars.f90:34: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: qevars.f90:56: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: qevars.f90:58: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: qevars.f90:60: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: qevars.f90:68: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: qevars.f90:70: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: qevars.f90:72: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: qevars.f90:74: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: qevars.f90:75: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: qevars.f90:77: Illegal preprocessor directive
qevars.f90:33:43:

     use io_files,   ONLY : nd_nmbr, prefix, outdir, tmp_dir, nwordwfc, iunwfc
                                           1
Error: Symbol ‘outdir’ referenced at (1) not found in module ‘io_files’
qevars.f90:73:43:

     use wvfct,      ONLY : npw, npwx, nbnd, igk, g2kin, wg, et, ecutwfc
                                           1
Error: Symbol ‘igk’ referenced at (1) not found in module ‘wvfct’
qevars.f90:73:63:

     use wvfct,      ONLY : npw, npwx, nbnd, igk, g2kin, wg, et, ecutwfc
                                                               1
Error: Symbol ‘ecutwfc’ referenced at (1) not found in module ‘wvfct’
qevars.f90:71:43:

     use wvfct,      ONLY : npw, npwx, nbnd, igk, g2kin, wg, et
                                           1
Error: Symbol ‘igk’ referenced at (1) not found in module ‘wvfct’
```

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Many more people will see your question. Tags are *very* important.

Comment: We are missing your code. The code is necessary. see [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Looks like you need the `-cpp` flag. That is just a guess, because I can't see the code.

Comment: @VladimirF thanks so much for the answer. `-cpp` is really the flag I need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error messages and warnings like

```
Warning: qevars.f90:30: Illegal preprocessor directive
```

are normally cased by Fortran code containing preprocessor directives but not preprocessed by the preprocessor. In gfortran use `-cpp` to enable the preprocessor or use file extensions with capital F (`.F`, `.F90`).

The lack of preprocessing can cause many following errors being reported.

Comment: Hi, I got a similar problem when installing enumlib <https://github.com/msg-byu/enumlib>, however, adding -cpp flag did not work in my macbook. Is there another way to fix the error "Symbol 'co_ca' referenced at (1) not found in module".

Comment: @BinhThien That is a completely different problem. Please open a separate question and show your code and the error messages.

Comment: I opened a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70450109/referenced-at-1-not-found-in-module-in-macbook-monterey