# Referenced at (1) not found in module in macbook monterey

Tags: gfortran

I tried to compile the code https://github.com/msg-byu/enumlib using gfortran on my macbook. However, it showed the following error.

```
 use io_utils, only: co_ca
                   1
Error: Symbol ‘co_ca’ referenced at (1) not found in module ‘io_utils’
make: *** [makeStr.o] Error 1
```

I tried to add -cpp flag but it did not worked. Could you please help me out?
Here is the Makefile.

When I added `co_ca` to define in `public`, it worked but showed some warnings like the following:

```
gfortran -fPIC -g -fbounds-check -Wall -ffree-line-length-none -fno-underscoring -I../symlib/src -c io_utils.f90
io_utils.f90:52:98:

   52 |   subroutine read_struct_enum_out(title,LatDim,pLV,nD,d,k,eq,Nmin,Nmax,eps,full,label,digit,cRange,fname)
      |                                                                                                  1
Warning: Unused dummy argument ‘crange’ at (1) [-Wunused-dummy-argument]
gfortran -fPIC -g -fbounds-check -Wall -ffree-line-length-none -fno-underscoring -I../symlib/src -c arrow_related.f90
gfortran -fPIC -g -fbounds-check -Wall -ffree-line-length-none -fno-underscoring -I../symlib/src -c tree_class.f90
tree_class.f90:483:18:

  483 |           index = index + binomial(nLeft-site_i, count(new_labeling(site_i:)==1)-1)
      |                  1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from INTEGER(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
tree_class.f90:224:14:

  224 |           I = I - nchoosek(ell-1,t-1)
      |              1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from INTEGER(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
tree_class.f90:110:37:

  110 |           self%branches(species_i) = nchoosek(sum(self%colors(species_i:)),self%colors(species_i))
      |                                     1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from INTEGER(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
gfortran -fPIC -g -fbounds-check -Wall -ffree-line-length-none -fno-underscoring -I../symlib/src -c labeling_related.f90
labeling_related.f90:1624:9:

 1624 |     nl = multinomial(iConc)
      |         1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from INTEGER(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
labeling_related.f90:1550:18:

 1550 |           count = count + (-1)**p*nchoosek(m,p)*tc
      |                  1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from INTEGER(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
labeling_related.f90:942:8:

  942 |     x = idx
      |        1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from INTEGER(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
labeling_related.f90:946:14:

  946 |        bnml = binomial(i-1,t-1)
      |              1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from INTEGER(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
labeling_related.f90:918:21:

  918 |              xTemp = xTemp + binomial(nLeft - iM, count(mask(iM:)==1)-1)
      |                     1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from INTEGER(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
labeling_related.f90:888:15:

  888 |        C(iK) = binomial(nLeft,conc(iK))
      |               1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from INTEGER(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
labeling_related.f90:727:20:

  727 |              quot = labIndx/multiplier(ilab) ! How many times does k(i) divide the number
      |                    1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from INTEGER(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
labeling_related.f90:310:83:

  310 |   SUBROUTINE generate_permutation_labelings(k,n,nD,perm,lab,iConc,parLabel,parDigit,degeneracy_list,fixed_cells)
      |                                                                                   1
Warning: Unused dummy argument ‘pardigit’ at (1) [-Wunused-dummy-argument]
labeling_related.f90:58:64:

   58 |   SUBROUTINE recursively_stabilized_enum(perm,conc,symsize,knary,SNF,LT,HNF,HNFcnt,hnf_degen,nfound,scount,fixOp,iBlock,equivalencies,inactives,permIndx,allowed,fixedcell,aperms)
      |                                                                1
Warning: Unused dummy argument ‘knary’ at (1) [-Wunused-dummy-argument]
labeling_related.f90:1487:35:

 1487 |   SUBROUTINE make_translation_group(d,trans)
      |                                   ^
Warning: ‘make_translation_group’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
labeling_related.f90:1583:52:

 1583 |   SUBROUTINE generate_disjoint_permutation_labelings(k,n,nD,perm,lab,iConc,parLabel,parDigit)
      |                                                    ^
Warning: ‘generate_disjoint_permutation_labelings’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
gfortran -fPIC -g -fbounds-check -Wall -ffree-line-length-none -fno-underscoring -I../symlib/src -c enumeration_routines.f90
gfortran -fPIC -g -fbounds-check -Wall -ffree-line-length-none -fno-underscoring -I../symlib/src -c derivative_structure_generator.f90
derivative_structure_generator.f90:1600:17:

 1600 |     size_count = size_count + this_count*nHNF
      |                 1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from INTEGER(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
derivative_structure_generator.f90:1601:18:

 1601 |     total_count = total_count + this_count*nHNF
      |                  1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from INTEGER(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
gfortran -fPIC -g -fbounds-check -Wall -ffree-line-length-none -fno-underscoring -I../symlib/src -c enumeration_utilities.f90
enumeration_utilities.f90:86:57:

   86 |     if (minkowskiReduce) call minkowski_reduce_basis(sLV,sLV,eps)
      |                                                         1
Warning: Same actual argument associated with INTENT(OUT) argument ‘out’ and INTENT(IN) argument ‘in’ at (1)
ar ru libenum.a sorting.o enumeration_types.o io_utils.o arrow_related.o tree_class.o labeling_related.o enumeration_routines.o derivative_structure_generator.o enumeration_utilities.o
ar: creating archive libenum.a
ranlib  libenum.a
gfortran -fPIC -g -fbounds-check -Wall -ffree-line-length-none -fno-underscoring -I../symlib/src -c ../aux_src/makeStr.f90
../aux_src/makeStr.f90:13:67:

   13 | integer ioerr, iline, ic, i, ilab, pgOps, nD, hnfN, iAt, jAt, iSpec, nSpec, idx, foutput_unit
      |                                                                   1
Warning: Unused variable ‘ispec’ declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
gfortran  -o makestr.x makeStr.o libenum.a ../symlib/src/libcomparestructs.a ../symlib/src/libutils.a ../symlib/src/libsym.a ../symlib/src/librational.a ../symlib/src/libcombinatorics.a
```

Comment: Are you compiling a self written part, using the mentioned library as it looks like the referenced `co_ca` is  a `private`  member in the library

Comment: co_ca is writen in module io_utils "call co_ca(10,err)". I do not see it in the library.

Comment: A private function can be used in the module it is defined but will, most likely, not be exported and not written to the `.mod` file

Comment: I am not sure what I should do. I have reported to the coder, but until now no response.

Comment: Coming back from being dean and teaching again, I've been too busy to keep up with all my github repos. At the end of April, I hope to start addressing all the outstanding issues and PRs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well as long as the people from the repository haven't reacted, probably the best solution for you at this moment is to adjust your local code.

In the file `src/io_utils.f90` you could change the lines (currently in master 11 and 12):

```
public read_input, write_lattice_symmetry_ops, write_rotperms_list, read_in_cells_from_file, &
       read_struct_enum_out, read_arrows, check_for_fixed_cells
```

to

```
public read_input, write_lattice_symmetry_ops, write_rotperms_list, read_in_cells_from_file, &
       read_struct_enum_out, read_arrows, check_for_fixed_cells, co_ca
```

so just add `co_ca` to the current master line 12.

Disclaimer: I didn't compile the project.

Comment: Thank you. It works with some warming "Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from INTEGER(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]".

Comment: Wheer do you see these warning, full reference please.

Comment: I post the warning here [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DTsUbaNfCWuW3mtx1iXdn6sBFdn__cZ9/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Add it to your question, i.e. the full text of the messages you found (or at least the beginning), most people don't want to see it in external links (risk) and they might not be persistent.

Comment: I added the warnings above.

Comment: @BinhThien You can not do much about those warnings if you do not want to start fixing the code at a large scale. They are unrelated to your original error. Either you ignore them or you silence them or you have tp start investigating in detail and start reasoning about all possible sizes of those values. Or you can use some promotion option to move all integers to 8 bytes, but that is risky and may cause its own set of problems. My advice is ignore.

Comment: Latest update fixes the things discussed here. The conversion warning can't be avoided or fixed, but I removed `-Wall` from the makefile so it won't bother people any more.